# Display 10 most recent database entries in a HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a PHP application, where I need to display the 10 most recent MySQL database entries in a HTML table.

I'm not too sure how I'd go about doing this.

My database holds the date the item was submitted, and the time (in separate columns).

How would I retrieve the 10 most recent database entries in a HTML table?

**Edit:** Is it possible using ajax?

Comment: use `ORDER BY`and LIMIT.

Comment: Start by writing some code and trying and then come by and show us your code with any current problems you're having with it. Don't forget you can `ORDER BY` and use `LIMIT`.

Comment: Are you using autoincremental Id or storing the submit date?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT some, colums
FROM table
ORDER BY submitdate DESC, submittime DESC
LIMIT 10
```